# Check CheckBox inside inner Repeater from outer Repeater checked in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater, nested-repeater

There are two CheckBoxes one is in outer Repeater and other is inside inner Repeater.

I would like to automatically check CheckBox of inner Repeater when checked the outer Repeater's CheckBox.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repOuter" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOuter" runat="server" 
             OnCheckedChanged="chkOuter_CheckedChanged" />

        <asp:Repeater ID="repInner" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInner" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void chkOuter_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // can't have access to inner CheckBox placed inside Inner Repeater
    CheckBox innerCheckBox; // how?

    innerCheckBox.Checked = true; // want to check it
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this(though untested).

```
CheckBox chkOuter = (sender as CheckBox);
RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)chkOuter.NamingContainer;   
Repeater rp = item.FindControl("repInner") as Repeater;
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rp.Items)
{    
    (item.FindControl("chkInner") as CheckBox).Checked = chkOuter.Checked;
}
```